# NSCache crashing app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nscache

My iOS app project keeps crashing when using NSCache with the console saying

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCache setObject:forKey:cost:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: productAllergyCache)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c9a012 0x10d7e7e 0x1c6f7d9 0x1c6f613 0x4211 0xfd1c7 0xfd232 0xfd4da 0x1148e5 0x1149cb 0x114c76 0x114d71 0x11589b 0x115e93 0x115a88 0x2c59 0xcb285 0xcb4ed 0xad55b3 0x1c59376 0x1c58e06 0x1c40a82 0x1c3ff44 0x1c3fe1b 0x1bf47e3 0x1bf4668 0x1bffc 0x20bd 0x1fe5) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception (lldb)
```

My code looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    detailViewmySQL = [[NSCache alloc]init];

    [self.detailViewmySQL setObject:productName forKey:@"productNameCache"];
    [self.detailViewmySQL setObject:productDescription forKey:@"productDescriptionCache" cost:1];
    [self.detailViewmySQL setObject:productImage forKey:@"productImageCache"];
    [self.detailViewmySQL setObject:productAllergy forKey:@"productAllergyCache"];
    [self.detailViewmySQL setObject:productQuantity forKey:@"productQuantityCache"];
    [self.detailViewmySQL setObject:productPrice forKey:@"productPriceCache"];

    self.title = [self.detailViewmySQL objectForKey:@"productNameCache"];

    outProductName.text = [self.detailViewmySQL objectForKey:@"productNameCache"];

    outProductDescription.text = [self.detailViewmySQL objectForKey:@"productDescriptionCache"];
    outProductImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.detailViewmySQL objectForKey:@"productImageCache"]]]];
    outProductAllergy.text = [self.detailViewmySQL objectForKey:@"productAllergyCache"];
    outProductQuantity.text = [self.detailViewmySQL objectForKey:@"productQuantityCache"];
    outProductPrice.text = [self.detailViewmySQL objectForKey:@"productPriceCache"];
}
```

Data is set here and passed to the above implementation file

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Passing data to view controller
    detailedViewController *productinfo = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bakeryDetails"];

    //Retrieve current user array
    foodProducts *currentProduct = [bakeryProductArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Pass data to variables of detailedviewcontroller
    productinfo.productName = currentProduct.productName;
    productinfo.productImage = currentProduct.productImgUrl;
    productinfo.productQuantity = currentProduct.productquantity;
    productinfo.productPrice = currentProduct.productPrice;
    productinfo.productAllergy = currentProduct.productAllergy;
    productinfo.productDescription = currentProduct.productDescription;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:productinfo animated:YES];
}
```

I have tried setting the cost and setTotalCostLimit but still crashes, anyone got a clue on what I am doing wrong?

Evil

Comment: According to the error message, productAllergy is nil. A nil value cannot be set in a NSDictionary or NSCache.

Comment: Sorted that but got -[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dcb678
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dcb678'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: I suspect you want `productAllergy` to be a `NSString`, right? Now you are storing a `NSNull` instead of a `nil`, which made you through the first problem, but now you need to check for `NSNull` when you use that value. It will be easier if you show where `productAllergy` comes from.

Comment: @Evilelement In both cases, the error message is telling you precisely what's happening and I'd encourage you look at those messages more carefully. Your original question said "attempt to insert nil value (productAllergyCache)", which tells you precisely what the issue was. This updated error, "NSNull isEqualToString", is telling you that you tried calling "isEqualToString" for a `NSNull` object (i.e. you're storing a `[NSNull null]` and using it somewhere where you were obviously intending to use a string. While the error looks complicated, isn't it telling you precisely what's wrong?

Comment: @Evilelement As an aside, why are you using a `NSCache` to hold your `detailViewmySQL`? That seems very dangerous. Are you ok if it decided, because it was low on memory, to just discard that information? If you're checking everytime you retrieve data and making sure it's not `nil` and going back to persistent storage, then that's fine, but I wonder if you've done that...

Comment: Sorted the problem. It came from mySQL database with varchar with symbol. Pushing a null back to the app property productPrice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you declared your `detailViewmySQL` as strong?

You can verify if the length of your string is > 0, if true you set that value. This will prevent crashes.